# send a message to client email address from my android application

Tags: android, email

- I need to send a message to client email address.Client mail id was
  `ssteph9220@gmail.com`.
- I never need to give a client email address in    output.I need to
  give that client email address as static.

**ContactFragment.java:**

```
view.findViewById(R.id.textView10).setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String name=edit1.getText().toString();       
        String e_mail = edit2.getText().toString();
        String subject = edit3.getText().toString();
        String message = edit4.getText().toString();

         Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, e_mail);


        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, name);
         i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);


        //i.setType("message/rfc822");

        i.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"+"ssteph9220@gmail.com")); -->Client Email address for an example 

       //startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an Email client :"));
        }

    });
```

- So far I done a code like these.Finally the message was send
  successfully.
- But I check that email address.The message wasn't received.Anybody
  can help me with these.Thank you.

Comment: what is `static reference`?

Comment: @injecteer I need to give it as directly in coding

Comment: there's no such thing in java. you mean a `constant`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `mailto:`, you need to use `ACTION_SENDTO`, not `ACTION_SEND`.

Beyond that, the user must send the email -- all `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` will do is set up the message in the user's email app's "composer".

Comment: I changed it to `ACTION_SENDTO` now also the message send successfully but couldn't get the message in inbox.

Comment: @Stephen: Then you have a problem with your email app on the Android device, or a problem with the mail server, or a problem with the mail client for the recipient, or a problem with the email address. All `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` do is open up the email "composer" and fill in some information. Everything after that has nothing to do with your app.

Comment: pleasure to see you:) I just uncomment this line:`startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose an Email client :"));` thank you worked perfectly.